# json file serialization. Reflection

Tags: c#, json, рефлексия

Необходимо Передать в метод `string[]`, а на выходе получить значение объекта.

```
    location _locations;
public string city_location_data(string[] args)
{
    TextAsset mytxtData = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("locations");
    location _location = JsonUtility.FromJson<location>(mytxtData.text);
    var prop_value0 = _location.locations.GetType().GetProperty(args[0]).GetValue(_locations.locations);
    var prop_value1 = prop_value0.GetType().GetProperty(args[1]).GetValue(prop_value0);
    var prop_value2 = prop_value1.GetType().GetProperty(args[2]).GetValue(prop_value1);
}

Exception:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Структура настроена верно. Вот так все работает:

```
_locations.locations.city.tavern.guild;
```

Comment: Вопрос то в чем?

Comment: поправил вопрос